# comparing 4 dates with each other in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

consider i have 2 dates that user sends to me like below :

```
$from_date = $request->get('from_date');
$to_date= $request->get('from_date');
```

and in my table named history the column i have is something like below :

```
Schema::create('histories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->daetime('from');
        $table->datetime('to')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

so now what i want is when a user select a range of time i want to check if that time exist on table and if it exists i want to compare days one by one together and here is what i have tried so far :

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($from_date, $to_date);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
$dates = $period->toArray();
```

and for getting the all dates in colomn simply :

```
$date = History::all();
foreach($date as $x){
 $db_daterange = $x->from_date 
}
```

now for comparing dates i tried this :

```
 foreach($dates as $y){
     if($y->isSameDay($db_daterange)){
       dd('same day');
    }
}
```

OK i am not completely sure about the last part but here is what i want in general i want to get all the dates in database compare them with the given dates if the given date exits on among database dates then just simply echo something but i want to search through all columns of table and all dates from "from_date until "to_date"

Comment: Your `histories` table doesn't have `from_date`, but you access `$x->from_date` as `History` property somehow

Answer (score -1):

you can try with whereBetween

```
History::whereBetween('from', ['2019-01-01', '2019-03-31'])->get()
```